# aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: no input files

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, linux-kernel

In general, I restarted the collection and the log is the following:

```
root@W-PC:/home/w-pc/kernel_dev/android_kernel_huawei_hi6210sft# make -j5
CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
GEN     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
CHK     include/generated/compile.h
LD      init/mounts.o
/home/w-pc/kernel_dev/gcc-linaro-4.9.4-2017.01-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: no input files
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:454: init/mounts.o] Ошибка 1 (Error 1)
make[1]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…(Waiting for tasks to complete...)
LD      arch/arm64/crypto/sha1-ce.o
/home/w-pc/kernel_dev/gcc-linaro-4.9.4-2017.01-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: no input files
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:454: arch/arm64/crypto/sha1-ce.o] Ошибка 1
make: *** [Makefile:883: arch/arm64/crypto] Ошибка 2
make: *** Ожидание завершения заданий… (Waiting for tasks to complete...)
make: *** [Makefile:883: init] Ошибка 2 (Error 2)
CHK     kernel/config_data.h
root@W-PC:/home/w-pc/kernel_dev/android_kernel_huawei_hi6210sft#
```

Google has not yet given any solutions ...
As for the line numbers of Makefile, then they are like this:

scripts / Makefile.build

```
454: $ (call if_changed, link_multi-y)
```

line 883 is not in this macafile (makefile)

line 454 in the kernel directory is like this:

```
export KBUILD_AFLAGS AFLAGS_KERNEL AFLAGS_MODULE
```

line 883 should be like this:

```
$ (Q) $ (MAKE) $ (build) = $ @
```

In the makefile along the path `arch/arm64/crypto` there are no lines with such numbers.

Postscript: It is not clear how the kernel was under 4.0 EMUI, but this is under 4.1. Yes, that is right, it stayed the same... weird.

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: please tell me how to solve this issue

Comment: apparently there are no specialists here

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem with the kernel source
type these commands:
**mkdir ../out && make -j4 O=../out**
it will compile